# Android Accessibility: sending several accessibility events on a single touch

Tags: android, checkbox, accessibility

Inside one of my recycle view adapters, I have a layout which displays an image and a checkbox.

I am adding accessibility to the app, and I want it so that when a user touches a picture, it will get a reading of the image and the current state of the checkbox (as in, "checked" or "unchecked", which is what the accessibility assistant reads,  not `true` or `false`)

The two separate lines of code which I have used fit my purpose are as follows:

```
myImageView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED);
myCheckbox.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED);
```

But if I run that call on the click event, the first instruction is cut short and only the second one is heard. So I believe this might not be the way to go. I probably have to use all of the Accessibility classes provided by Android, but I have no clue where to start.

What should I do for the voice feedback to read "Image one, checked... Image two, unchecked".

Additional info:
I cannot use strings to get the wanted value from the checkbox boolean because the app is multilingual and instead of having to get all the string resources I would rather take advantage of the system.

Thank you,
everyone, for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both items in a linearlayout and/or you can market the "Image one" part as a label for the checkbox. Both examples are shown below and taken from the link below them.

```
<LinearLayout    
   android:id="@+id/consumedContainer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
   android:id="@+id/coffeeLimitLabel"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:labelFor="@id/coffeeLimitValue"
   android:text="@string/coffee_limit_label"
   android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>
```

https://www.raywenderlich.com/182100/android-accessibility-tutorial-getting-started